# Swapping lines in text with unknown lines using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have 5 big text files, and I want to copy only one line from one of the files, and replace the same lines in the other files. Each line starts the same, only the end is different, and the line is unique.

After browsing many options, this is what I got now (for one of the files):

```
with open(fileNumberOne) as f1:
    for line1 in f1:
        if "FUSE_ROOT_DIR = " in line1:
            with open(fileNumberTwo) as f2:
                for line2 in f2:
                    newText = f2.read()
                    if "FUSE_ROOT_DIR = " in line2in :
                        newText = f2.read().replace(line2in , line1)
                    with open(fileNumberTwo, "w") as f2:
                        f2.write(newText)
```

"FUSE_ROOT_DIR = " is the identifier for the line that needs to be changed, the value from fileNumberOne is the correct one, and I need to swap the value for fileNumberTwo, and the line is unique so no need to worry about getting suddenly 2 lines that include the words "FUSE_ROOT_DIR".

The result is that the line won't change, and also the first line in fileNumberTwo is deleted (it starts with ###, maybe it has something to do with it?).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you assign something to `line2in`? Maybe it would help to disentangle the code to find the problem, I mean write a section that gets the line from file 1 and a section that replaces the lines in the other files, don't put it all in one nested block of `with` and `if` clauses.

Comment: It's written like so because I wanted to find the line in f1. But now I see it would make more sense to first find it, then use it in the rest of the files... won't fix it still, but clears things :) thanks

Comment: Did you try it with the code from my answer? If your files are very large, I'd suggest you try the `fileinput` option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an illustration of my comment: you could do it in two steps, e.g.

```py
token = 'FUSE_ROOT_DIR '
with open(file1, 'r') as fobj: # 1 - find your "reference" line
    for line in fobj:
        if token in line:
            ref_line = line
            break # skip the rest of the lines

if ref_line: # 2 - if it was found, replace it in the other files  
    with open(file2, 'r+') as fobj: # loop this for all your other files
        content = fobj.readlines() # read everything to a variable and modify that
        content = [ref_line if token in l else l for l in content]
        fobj.seek(0) # reset file pointer to beginning of file
        fobj.writelines(content) # overwrite with modified content
```

Another option for step #2 would be to use the `fileinput` module to do the replacement "in-place":

```py
import fileinput        

with fileinput.input(file2, inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:   
        if token in line:
            line = ref_line
        print(line.strip())
```

Comment: I didn't quite get the following line:
```
content = [ref_line if token in l else l for l in content]
```
Do you mean to write the logic inside? Is there a way to do it in one line, because I didn't understand the "in l else l for l in content". Maybe just a semantic that I'm unfamiliar with, so would love an explanation :)

Comment: `content` will be a `list` of strings from the text file. The line you refer to will go through all elements of the list (`for l in content`) and use the `ref_line` if the `token` is found in `l`. It's a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: First of all: It works :) So thank you very much for that!
Secondly: Thanks for the explanation, that was super useful as well.
Thanks!